# I'd like configure IndefiniteWaitOneShotStartupCheckStrategy by properties, not using Java class on testcontainer

Tags: testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I need use "Indefinite one shot startup strategy example" by testcontainer.properties.
How could I configure IndefiniteWaitOneShotStartupCheckStrategy using properties?

For real, I'd like to configure this three examples by properties, but I don't know how to do this:

```
container.withStartupCheckStrategy(
  new IndefiniteWaitOneShotStartupCheckStrategy()
);
```

```
container.waitingFor(
  Wait.forLogMessage("Completed: ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE XEPDB1 SAVE STATE", 1)
);
```

```
container.withStartupTimeoutSeconds(30);
```

Reference:
https://www.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/#indefinite-one-shot-startup-strategy-example

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for now.

See discussion here: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/discussions/4302